# Проверка температуры через регулярные выражения C#

Tags: c#, wpf, регулярные-выражения

Пользователем вводится строка. Проверить, соответствует ли она температуре воздуха: целое число со знаком «плюс» или «минус» или без знака, может быть 0, но с 0 число начинаться не может; после числа должен идти один пробел и обозначение шкалы (С или F).

Проблема в данной строке. Все получается по условию, но 0 выводит со знаком + и - , то есть вот так + 0 С, что неверно. Как решить данную проблему?

`Regex temperatura = new Regex(@"^[+-]?\W*(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:[,.]\d+)?\-*(\.\d+)?\W*[CF]\z");`

Comment: Откуда у вас взялись `\D`? Должны быть только `\d`. Приведите пример строки и желаемый результат.

Comment: Получается в итоге должна получиться температура вида + 23 С, иначе должно выводиться сообщение об ошибке. Но проблема в том, что нулевая температура в виде + 0 С обозначается как верная и это надо как то исправить

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей._

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте взять за основу такое выражение:

```
Regex temperatura = new Regex(@"^(0\s*?[CF])|^([+-]?\s*[1-9]\d*\s*[CF])");
```

Или еще короче:

```
Regex temperatura = new Regex(@"^(0|[+-]?\s*[1-9]\d*)\s*[CF]");
```

В начале должен быть либо ноль, либо число (со знаком или без).

В условиях Вы пишите про целое число, но делаете проверку на присутствие точки с запятой и еще много чего, что и привело к усложнению задачи.

Перед составлением регулярного выражения, полезно пройти глазами последовательно по тексту и проговорить логику разбора про себя. И уже после этого переносить на язык РВ.

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вся проблема в том, что при нулевом значении + и - в начале не допускаются, но не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: Приведенное мною выражение не допускает 0 со знаком. Что еще Вы хотите реализовать?

Comment: Можно ли это как то написать через WPF?

Comment: Конечно можно, код проверки не изменится. На поставленную Вами задачу я привел решение, а также добавил результат с кодом на C#.

Comment: вся проблема в том, что у меня все равно пропускает 0 со знаком

Comment: Вот пример работы: [ссылка](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%280%7c%5b%2b-%5d%3f%5cs*%5b1-9%5d%5cd*%29%5cs*%5bCF%5d&i=%2b+0+C%0d%0a-23+C%0d%0a-+0+F%0d%0a-+09+C%0d%0a%2b205C&o=m)

Comment: если по идее это должно работать и в впф, то ничего не работает

Comment: @bokuto в WPF другой шарп с другими регулярками? Ваш вопрос в принципе не относится к впф.

Comment: @aepot это не моя прихоть, а задание от преподавателя, к сожалению ничего с этим поделать не могу

Comment: С чем? Я вам о том, что регулярки везде одинаково работают.

Comment: но дело в том, что ошибки не исправились